# Batch script printing only last line of file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to get some text from a file and displaying it. When I print the values I am getting only last line of file two times.

```
for /F %A in (E:\auto_s3\fol.txt) do (
setlocal
set m=%A 
setlocal
set k=%m:~1,-1%
echo %k%)
```

fol.txt

```
//LogShare/sapbatch01/audit-sapbatch01
//LogShare/sapdial18/audit-sapdial18
```

Comment: What characters are you trying to remove from the beginning and end of each line in your file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting single character variables are ugly. Also, you need `enabledelayedexpansion`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F %A in (E:\auto_s3\fol.txt) do (
   set mvar=%A 
   set kvar=!mvar:~1,-1!
   echo !kvar!
)
```

To run it in an actual batch file, add a `%` This:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F %%A in (E:\auto_s3\fol.txt) do (
   set mvar=%%A 
   set kvar=!mvar:~1,-1!
   echo !kvar!
)
```

Note! as for the other script to get previous day and day before, [here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352095/get-previous-and-day-before-previous-date-in-batch-filecmd/47352336#47352336) to the answer I created on something similar.

Comment: isn't it % instead of !. i am getting !kvar! two times. it reading file correctly now

Comment: Please take 2nd example and copy to notepad. Save the file as filename.cmd and then run batchfile. Add pause at the very end of the file when created.

Comment: PS! it must be `!` and not `%` as that is how expansion works. See `setlocal /?` from cmdline.

Comment: i am creating .bat file not .cmd

Comment: @sasi `bat` and `cmd` Same thing :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168738/discussion-between-gerhard-barnard-and-sasi).

Comment: Perfect. I got it correct. I am new to Batch scripting. Thank you so much :)

Comment: to be precise [bat and cmd are a little bit different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/148968/995714)